# How to display multiple images in horizontal nature in android

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have this logic to dynamically display multiple images programmatically in an imageview, ten images were displayed from the logic but i have all of the images slanted i.e vertical. I would like to have those images displayed horizontally

```
 ImageView iv;
 LinearLayout linear;

 linear = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.detail);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bug_empty);
            iv.setPadding(0,0,0,5);
            linear.addView(iv);
        }
```

Here is the for loop that iterates ten times to display the images, how can I possibly have them displayed horizontally together not vertically displayed or slanted as it is now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout resource for `R.id.detail`, set your LinearLayout as

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:orientation="horizontal"
/>
```